# CSS issue with list elements in Chrome & Safari (no issue in Firefox or IE)

Tags: css, debugging, safari, google-chrome

I'm looking for suggestions for debugging... If you view this site in Firefox or IE, it will look fine... check it in Safari or Google Chrome and the text contained within the list elements of the sliding panel does not display :(

http://theatricalbellydance.com/home/

Any debug suggestions?

```
here is my HTML

<div id="sliding_wrap">
<ul id="sliding_panels" class="slidingPanelsActivated">
<li class="sliding p1"><span class="title p1">Anasma (Director)
<div class="name"></div>
<p></span>
<div class="panel_wrap"><strong>Anasma</strong> is Performance Arts Dancer, Teacher and Choreographer. To her, dance is an expression of the self and of the soul that enables each dancer, whether they are new to it or professional, to share their deepest emotions and to be in the Now. Anasma has been featured on various DVDs, including World Dance New York&#8217;s &#8220;<em>Bellydance Experience</em>&#8221; DVD and &#8220;<em>Fantasy Bellydance</em>&#8221; DVD.  In 2007, she sang alongside Pete List in the album &#8220;Songs for Kassar&#8221;. In 2009, she recorded her first instructional DVD &#8220;<em>Bellydance Hip Hop Liquid Fusion</em>&#8220;. A new instructional DVD with Anasma, &#8220;<em>Wave Explosion! Bellydance Hip Hop Liquid Fusion</em>&#8221; was just released in February 2010.  Anasma performs and teaches in <em>Europe</em>, <em>North America</em> and <em>Asia</em>. She is the <em>co-founder</em> and <em>co-director</em> of the New York Theatrical Bellydance Conference. You can visit her website at <a href="http://www.anasmadance.com" target="_blank">www.AnasmaDance.com</a><a class="readmore" href="bios#anasma">Read Full Bio</a></div>

</li>
<li class="sliding p2"><span class="title p2">Ranya Renée (Director)
<div class="name"></div>
<p></span>
<div class="panel_wrap"><strong>Ranya Renée</strong> began her performing career more than 30 years ago as a theater actress and comedienne, and moved to NYC in 1992 to continue her work as a theater director. She was gradually sidetracked by bellydance until it became her life! One of New York City’s leading Egyptian-style dancer-instructors, Ranya specializes in teaching holistic technique and theatrical performance skills &#038; coaching. She produces live events in New York and tours internationally.  Ranya’s signature “<em>Breathwork for Performance</em>” method has enabled thousands of artists worldwide to more effectively connect with their own art, and with their audiences. She strives to create a supportive atmosphere in her workshops for both technical precision and artistic growth. Ranya&#8217;s instructional DVDs Bellydance &#8220;<em>Egyptian Style: The Baladi</em>&#8221; and &#8220;<em>Modern Oriental</em>&#8221; have earned rave reviews from dancers worldwide. This year she launched her own company, <em>Ginger City Productions</em>, to produce more teaching and performance videos. For more info visit her website at <a href="http://ranya.net" target="_blank">www.Ranya.net</a>.<a class="readmore" href="bios#ranya">Read Full Bio</a></div>

</li>
<li class="sliding p3"><span class="title p3">Aszmara
<div class="name"></div>
<p></span>
<div class="panel_wrap"><strong>Aszmara</strong> &#8220;Dance is emotion in motion&#8221; describes accurately the quality of Aszmara’s dance. She impresses through her expressive stage presence and interprets the music with her own blend of modern and ethnic Arab and Turkish dance which The <em>New York Times</em> describes as &#8220;intense&#8221;.  Throughout her over three decade career, performances range from cabaret entertainment to full concert stage creating themed concert events, folkloric and innovative dances.   Workshop sponsors in the USA and Europe repeatedly bring her back for her vast knowledge and informed teaching conveying technical and performance skills.  As one of the leading figures in the field of the Oriental Dance, she was one of the <em>founders/principal dancers</em> of the <em>AMMED</em> Award Winning Middle Eastern Dance Company <em>Oriental Images</em> as well as co-founder/co-director of <em>SaZ Dance Theatre</em>, a multi-cultural woman’s dance company.  Aszmara&#8217;s instructional DVD, &#8220;<em>Belly Dance&#8230; The Secret Desire</em>&#8221;  won high praise from <em>Habibi magazine</em>.  &#8220;Dance is Emotion in Motion&#8221; <a href="http://www.aszmara.com" target="_blank">visit Aszmara.com</a>.<a class="readmore" href="bios#aszmara">Read Full Bio</a></div>

</li>
<li class="sliding p4"><span class="title p4">Lotus Niraja
<div class="name"></div>
<p></span>
<div class="panel_wrap"><strong>Lotus Niraja</strong> is a professional Middle Eastern dance artist specializing in Urban, Contemporary and Modern Egyptian and Lebanese belly dance styles. As one of the top performers and instructors on the East Coast, Lotus is widely recognized for her dance style, dramatic energy, and vibrant interpretation and technique. Known for her drum solos and shimmy technique, her dance style is dynamic, infused with glamour and style! Lotus teaches Belly Dance classes and offers private lessons as well as national and international workshops. In her classes and workshops, Lotus combines elegance, grace and crisp movement technique with stage dynamics and audience participation in order to help the student give a polished theatrical performance. She offers an extensive library of workshop topics including <em>Raks Modern</em>, the <em>Art of Belly-o-graphy</em>, <em>Raks Sabor</em>, <em>the Icing on the Drum Solo</em>, <em>Egyptian Style Dance Boot camp</em> and <em>Shimmilicious Shimmies</em>.<a class="readmore" href="bios#lotus">Read Full Bio</a></div>

</li>
<li class="sliding p5"><span class="title p5">Hanan
<div class="name"></div>
<p></span>
<div class="panel_wrap"><strong>Hanan</strong> (Tiffany Madera, M.A.), has been a leader in her field for over a decade. Specializing in contemporary folkloric styles of Egypt, Yousry Sharif wrote “Hanan can easily pass as a native dancer of Cairo… this is no easy task”. <em>The Miami Herald</em> describes hanan as “boundary crossing”, “bold” and “a dominant force in contemporary dance”. She is the Founder of Cuba’s first Bellydance Troupe and band; Aisha’ Al-Hanan and has created and developed two documentary films on the subject. She is currently in post production of her film “<em>Havana Habibi</em>” in collaboration with Beeloved Creations. Hanan is a prolific and avante-garde dance theater artist and is a critically acclaimed director and producer of the <em>Habibi Trilogy</em> (Hip Hop Bellydance hybrid theatre) and Hanan with Other Friendly Gods and Goddesses, which made the <em>Miami Herald Top 10 Performances of the Year</em>. Hanan is a world renowned protégé of Tamalyn Dallal and Yousry Sharif. <a class="readmore" href="bios#hanan">Read Full Bio</a></div>

</li>
<li class="sliding p6"><span class="title p6">Fahtiem
<div class="name"></div>
<p></span>
<div class="panel_wrap"><strong>Fahtiem</strong> is a multi-award winning choreographer, master instructor, international superstar performer, highly renowned in the world of Middle Eastern Dance. Featured in <em>Time Magazine</em>, numerous TV, Commercials, Movies and in many performance and instructional DVD&#8217;s. She is listed in several editions of International Who’s Who of Professional &#038; Business Women. Her awards include: <em>International Cultural Diploma of Honor</em>, <em>Woman of the Year</em>, <em>International Academy of Middle Eastern Dance</em>, <em>Dancer of the Year</em>, <em>Entertainer of the Year</em>, <em>Choreographer of the Year</em>, <em>Teacher of the Year</em>. <em>American Academy of Middle Eastern Dance (New York), Hall of Fame-Lifetime Achievement</em>, and <em>MECDA Hall of Fame</em>. Fahtiem has taught and performed globally, including in Egypt at the Ahlan Wa Sahlan Festivals in 2007 and 2009, while maintaining a full teaching schedule in Los Angeles Ca. including college level dance courses. [...] <a class="readmore" href="bios#fahtiem">Read Full Bio</a></div>

</li>
<li class="sliding p7"><span class="title p7">Angelika Nemeth
<div class="name"></div>
<p></span>
<div class="panel_wrap"><strong>Angelika Nemeth</strong>, an internationally renowned artist who has received numerous awards for her teaching and performing, is on the <em>dance faculty of three California colleges</em> where she teaches accredited classes in Middle Eastern dance. She has produced and directed numerous critically acclaimed world dance concerts and co-sponsored the historic 1st and 2nd International Conference on Middle Eastern Dance. She was influential in the creation and development of Orange Coast College’s <em>World Dance Certificate Program</em>, which she now supervises. Her artistic legacy has significantly influenced her dance genre, especially in her home base of Southern California. Angelika trains and mentors many of today’s new dance stars, lectures at colleges and libraries and adjudicates belly dance competitions world-wide. She also organizes and leads dance study tours to the Middle East and is featured on numerous dance videos and in print media. Visit her website <a href="http://www.angelikanemeth.com" target="_blank">www.AngelikaNemeth.com</a>.<a class="readmore" href="bios#angelika">Read Full Bio</a></div>
</li>
<li class="sliding p8"><span class="title p8">Sarah Johansson Locke

<div class="name"></div>
<p></span>
<div class="panel_wrap"><strong>Sarah Johansson Locke </strong>is a performer, choreographer, and teacher whose work draws on a deep knowledge of the body as well several forms of traditional and contemporary dance, theater, yoga, and somatic modalities. As the <em>Artistic Director of Alchemy Performance</em>, she directs and performs with two companies; teaches dance, yoga, and anatomy; and curates and produces events. Her dance explores sacred space, that within us and that around us. Sarah has extensive training in a wide range of contemporary and folk dance styles including Ballet, Modern, Tribal and Tribal Fusion Bellydance, North Indian Khatak, Butoh, West African, North African, and many styles of Rom (Gypsy) dance including Rajasthani, Turkish, Russian, Bulgarian, Croatian, and Spanish (Flamenco). <a class="readmore" href="bios#sarahlocke">Read Full Bio</a></div>
</li>
<li class="sliding p9"><span class="title p9">Kaeshi Chaie
<div class="name"></div>
<p></span>
<div class="panel_wrap"><strong>Kaeshi Chai</strong> is an internationally recognized performer and instructor. She is the <em>director</em> of the professional company, <em>Bellyqueen Dance Theater</em>, the healing community <em>PURE (Public Urban Ritual Experiment)</em> as well as the <em>Rising Sirens</em>. In 2003-2004, she was part of the <em>Bellydance Superstars</em>, and held the position of <em>dance captain</em> for the 2004 US &#038; Canadian Spring Tour. She has performed at <em>Central Park&#8217;s Summerstage</em>, <em>Lincoln Center Out of Doors</em>, <em>Folie&#8217;s Begere in Paris</em>, <em>Bloomsbury Theater in London</em>, <em>Teatro Smeraldo in Milan</em> and has made television appearances on <em>Conan O&#8217;Brien</em> as well as <em>BBC&#8217;s Blue Peter</em>. Recently, she was invited to team up with the one and only <em>Jillina</em> for her <a href="http://www.bellydancerevolution.com" target="_blank">Bellydance Revolution</a> project. <a class="readmore" href="bios#kaeshi">Read Full Bio</a>  </div>

</li>
<li class="sliding p10"><span class="title p10">Samara
<div class="name"></div>
<p></span>
<div class="panel_wrap"><strong>Samara</strong>’s hallmark style, a blend of serene elegance, spiritual grace, earthy passion, and technical prowess is the result of a life long commitment to Oriental Dance. Samara began dancing professionally in her teens, having already studied other dance forms extensively. In addition to her work with the <em>Near East Dance Group</em>, Samara has shared the stage with some of the most famous singing stars of the Middle East including, (to name a few), <em>Walid Tofic</em>, <em>Ragheb Alame</em>, <em>Sabah</em>, and <em>George Wassouf</em>. Samara was a part of Warda’s dazzling show at <em>Madison Square Garden</em>, <em>The Brooklyn Funk Essential at Irving Plaza</em> and danced with famed pop-fusion star <em>Alabina</em> at the <em>Beacon Theater</em>. She co-produced and appeared as an original member of the World Beat Extravaganza Ballet Exotiqa and danced with <em>Christina Aguillera</em> at <em>Radio City Music Hall for the MTV Music Awards</em>. Samara was a 1998 inductee into the <em>American Academy of Middle Eastern Dance Hall of Fame</em>. <a class="readmore" href="bios#samara">Read Full Bio</a></div>

</li>
<li class="sliding p11"><span class="title p11">Roula Said
<div class="name"></div>
<p></span>
<div class="panel_wrap"><strong>Roula Said</strong> is a dancer, musician and actor based in Toronto known for her authentic, innovative and compelling style and stage presence.  Of Palestinian roots, Roula co-leads Gypsy/Middle Eastern Funk Band, <em>Nomadica</em> with her husband David Buchbinder, produces the hippest global grooves dance party in Toronto, <em>FunkaBelly</em>, and teaches a unique holistic system of wave-infused movement, rhythm and vocalization at her school,  <em>Om Laila Bellydance</em>. Roula has appeared in numerous theatre and film productions over the years, including celebrated indie film director <em>Ruba Nadda</em>&#8217;s &#8220;<em>Sabah</em>&#8220;. More about Roula&#8217;s world: <a href="http://www.omlaila.com">www.Omlaila.com</a> &amp; <a href="http://www.funkabelly.com">www.FunkaBelly.com</a><a class="readmore" href="bios#roula">Read Full Bio</a></div>

</li>
<li class="sliding p12"><span class="title p12">JeniViva
<div class="name"></div>
<p></span>
<div class="panel_wrap"><strong>JeniViva</strong>  performs and teaches both Classical Turkish Cabaret and Gothic Fusion Bellydance in New York City.  She has also developed her own <em>Gothic Bellydance</em> technique entitled &#8220;<em>The Serpentine Method©</em>&#8220;. Jeniviva describes it as a technique that &#8220;fuses movements of Vict-Oriental, Gothic, Steampunk, Cabaret, Tribal Fusion, and Ritual Bellydance. The ultimate fusion of alternative Bellydance genres with a modern theatrical twist!&#8221; JeniViva has appeared on <em>The Conan O’Brien Show</em>, <em>the WB 11</em>, at <em>the House of Blues</em>, the <em>Rainbow Room</em>, and numerous prestigious nightclubs in NYC. JeniViva has performed for such clients as <em>Jay-Z</em>, <em>Marc Jacobs</em>, and <em>Esquire Magazine</em> and she recently had the pleasure of being cast as a featured dancer in the film <em>Sex in the City part 2</em>.<a class="readmore" href="bios#jeniviva">Read Full Bio</a></div>

</li>
<li class="sliding p13"><span class="title p13">Aepril Schaile
<div class="name"></div>
<p></span>
<div class="panel_wrap"><strong>Aepril Schaile</strong> is &#8220;<em>An American priestess of the Dark Goddess</em>&#8221; working through the ancient and ever-evolving arts of Bellydance, Music, Ritual Theater, and Divination. Aepril has taught and performed at curated events in <em>Paris</em>, <em>NYC</em>, <em>L.A.</em>, <em>Hollywood</em>, and <em>San Francisco</em>. Aepril directs <em>Exquisite Corpse Productions</em> and is <em>Artistic Director</em> of <em>Exquisite Corpse Dance Theatre</em>. Aepril teaches ongoing classes in Boston and Salem, MA, and teaches traditional, theatrical, and shamanistic Bellydance workshops nationwide and internationally. In performance, Aepril becomes Trickster, Warrior, Ghost, Storm, Grieving Mother, Killer, Snow Queen, Seductress… Aepril’s performances invoke the archetypal Feminine as a force of nature and magick. Aepril is an astrologer, musician and composer, dancer and dance teacher, writer and storyteller, mythologist, animal rights advocate, and witch. Aepril is an AAFA certified Group Fitness Instructor, and she holds an MFA in Interdisciplinary Art.<a class="readmore" href="bios#aepril">Read Full Bio</a></div>

</li>
<li class="sliding p14"><span class="title p14">Blanca
<div class="name"></div>
<p></span>
<div class="panel_wrap"><strong>Blanca</strong> Born in Mexico and based in New York City, Blanca is a dancer, choreographer, teacher, and workshop leader. Trained in diverse disciplines, her main love has always been bellydance and its many facets: a performing art, a social dance, a fitness practice, a storytelling device and one of the most powerful healing tools she has encountered. Credits include a dance scene for the upcoming film <em>Sex and the City 2</em>, <em>11 bellydance DVDs</em>, and a series of dance concerts at <em>Merce Cunningham Studio</em> with her previous dance collectives <em>Venus Uprising</em> and <em>CollexArts</em>. She is a faculty member at the <em>92Y</em>, teaches weekly classes at <em>Serena Studios</em> and leads workshops throughout the US and abroad. <a href="http://www.BlancaDance.com">www.BlancaDance.com</a>  <a href="http://www.SensualBellydance.com">www.SensualBellydance.com</a> <a href="http://www.YouTube.com/sensualbellydance">www.YouTube.com/sensualbellydance</a><a class="readmore" href="bios#blanca">Read Full Bio</a></div>

</li>
<li class="sliding p15"><span class="title p15">Elisheva
<div class="name"></div>
<p></span>
<div class="panel_wrap"><strong>Elisheva</strong> is an internationally acclaimed Tribal Fusion dancer from NYC, sought after for her signature fusion of aesthetics- Bellydance fused with trained classical dance, jazz forms, and hip hop’s popping &amp; locking.  She currently performs as a company member and the <em>Dance Captain</em> of  &#8220;<em>Bellyqueen</em>”, and is part of the creative NYC collective production team “<em>Venus Uprising</em>”.   She will be this years featured Artist and Instructor at <em>Hiptastic! 2010</em>, and teaches classes weekly in NYC and Long Island. Elisheva is currently featured on available performance DVDS and has 2 DVD instructionals available;  “<em>Tribal Fusion, Pop &amp; Lock</em>” and “<em>Hard Candy</em>”.<a class="readmore" href="bios#elisheva">Read Full Bio</a></div>

</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and here's my CSS

```
/*  -------------------------------  Instructor Sliding Panels  -------------------------------    */
h2.meet{
    margin: 0 0 10px -20px;
}
div#sliding_wrap{
    display: block;
    width: 794px;
    background: #151515;
    border: 1px solid #313131;
    margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
    padding: 2px 1px 0 2px;
}
div#sliding_wrap ul#sliding_panels a{
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
div#sliding_wrap ul#sliding_panels a:hover{
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#sliding_panels{
}

/* REQUIRED * the "slidingPanelsActivated" class added to container by the plug-in, allows for different presentation if JavaScript is disabled */
ul.slidingPanelsActivated {
display:block;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;

/* edit "padding" and "margin" with care, as they can mess things up across browser */
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 290px;
}

/* REQUIRED * the "slidingPanelsActivated" class added to container by the plug-in, allows for different presentation if JavaScript is disabled */
ul.slidingPanelsActivated li {
display:block;
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
/* "left" and "width" properties set automatically */
top: 0;

/* edit "padding" and "margin" with care, as they can mess things up across browser */
padding: 0;
margin: 0;

/* "height" of 100% recommended to keep panels all the same height as the container */
height:100%;
}

/* colors assigned to individual panels for demonstration, recommended to make a panel's background color same as container's background color */
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding{
    display: block;
    background: url(images/p_bg.jpg) repeat;
    position: relative;
}

ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.title{
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 346px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #646142;
    background: url(images/instr_panel_bg.png) top left repeat;
    padding: 0 1px;
    z-index: 10;
}

ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span div.name {
    height: 290px;
    width: 26px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}

ul#sliding_panels li.sliding div.panel_wrap{
    padding: 10px 5px 20px 160px;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 320px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
ul#sliding_panels li.p2 div, ul#sliding_panels li.p3 div, ul#sliding_panels li.p4 div, ul#sliding_panels li.p6 div, ul#sliding_panels li.p7 div, ul#sliding_panels li.p10 div, ul#sliding_panels li.p13 div{
    padding-left: 120px !important;
    font-size: 0.7em !important;    
}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding strong{
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFEFBC;
}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding a.readmore{
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #fff;
}



ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.p1 div.name {background: url(images/p1_title.png) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.p2 div.name {background: url(images/p2_title.png) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.p3 div.name {background: url(images/p3_title.png) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.p4 div.name {background: url(images/p4_title.png) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.p5 div.name {background: url(images/p5_title.png) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.p6 div.name {background: url(images/p6_title.png) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.p7 div.name {background: url(images/p7_title.png) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.p8 div.name {background: url(images/p8_title.png) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.p9 div.name {background: url(images/p9_title.png) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.p10 div.name {background: url(images/p10_title.png) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.p11 div.name {background: url(images/p11_title.png) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.p12 div.name {background: url(images/p12_title.png) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.p13 div.name {background: url(images/p13_title.png) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.p14 div.name {background: url(images/p14_title.png) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.sliding span.p15 div.name {background: url(images/p15_title.png) top left no-repeat;}


ul#sliding_panels li.p1 div.panel_wrap{background: url(images/p1_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.p2 div.panel_wrap{background: url(images/p2_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.p3 div.panel_wrap{background: url(images/p3_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.p4 div.panel_wrap{background: url(images/p4_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.p5 div.panel_wrap{background: url(images/p5_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.p6 div.panel_wrap{background: url(images/p6_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.p7 div.panel_wrap{background: url(images/p7_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.p8 div.panel_wrap{background: url(images/p8_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.p9 div.panel_wrap{background: url(images/p9_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.p10 div.panel_wrap{background: url(images/p10_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.p11 div.panel_wrap{background: url(images/p11_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.p12 div.panel_wrap{background: url(images/p12_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.p13 div.panel_wrap{background: url(images/p13_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.p14 div.panel_wrap{background: url(images/p14_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;}
ul#sliding_panels li.p15 div.panel_wrap{background: url(images/p15_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;}
```

Comment: I can see the ul li panels nicely with the text, i am using Chrome 5 on Ubuntu.

Comment: The panels should have text inside of them :(  The photos display OK but the text is not displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this particular bug was coming from the strange way that the WordPress admin panel turns returns into p tags.  Installed the [RAW] Html plugin and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is reporting the computed width of your DIVs with className of "panel_wrap" as being 75px, which probably means it is clipping your text. Try explicitly setting a width on those.

Comment: Good catch.  I updated it and the text is still not displaying though :(